# Convert JSX to text file

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm looking for a way to convert JSX files to .txt files - preferably with gulp, or any npm module. Any suggestions? Basically the opposite from gulp-txtjs.

Comment: JSX files are already text (because source code is text). Please provide more details about what you are trying to do. I assume you do not just want to rename files. Also, please read tag descriptions. [tag:jsx] is about something different.

Comment: What I want is to serve JSX components as text in my component documentation. So, you can click to view code.

Comment: As I said, the files are already text. You don't need to convert anything.

Comment: How can I serve components as plain text then?

Comment: Depends on how your documentation works. If you are using webpack you could use the raw loader.

Comment: I'm using browserify.